# Como fazer uma imagem de Docker de um app de Node que usa repo privado que requere ssh

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

Seguindo [este guia](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) do site do Node.js para criar uma imagem de Docker para um aplicativo de Node, tudo dá certo exceto quando se tem um repositório privado para um certo pacote de npm, como o seguinte snippet do `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  (...)
  "um-certo-pacote": "git+ssh://git@algumlugar.com:/algum/diretorio/um-certo-pacote.git",
  (...)
```

O servidor que tem o repo armazena a chave ssh do computador que faz o pedido pra clonar o pacote. Localmente tudo funciona, mas na hora de fazer um build, não dá certo porque o Docker não tem acesso a chave ssh.

```
$ docker build -t nbkhope/meu-aplicativo --add-host=algumlugar.com:123.45.67.89 .
```

> Ja pesquisei em vários locais e tentei copiar o arquivo com a chave pública de ssh, mas isso não é recomendado devido a motivos de segurança. Então qual é a maneira de fazer esse negócio funcionar de maneira segura, sem expor segredos?

Segue o Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ola, vejo duas opções,

1. Antes de fazer o build, fazer o download do pacote, que estará então disponivel para ser adcionado ao build
2. Adcionar uma chave em uma build multi-stage, em que um estágio adciona-se a chave e faz o download, e a outra copia-se o pacote sem adcionar a chave

```
FROM node:6 as base
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./

FROM base as builder # esta imagem nao recebera tag, e ficara no sistema marcada como <none>
# Adcionar chave, seja por copia de arquivo ou variavel de ambiente
RUN npm install

FROM base as final #esta será a imagem final
COPY . .
COPY --from builder <diretório de pacotes> <diretório de pacotes>
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```